# How do I find the even elements in a list of items?

Tags: java, list, listitem

```
public class ListItem {

    final int number;
    ListItem next;

    public static ListItem evenElements(ListItem ls) {
        ListItem l = ls.duplicate();
        if(ls == null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < ls.length(); i++){

                if(ls.number % 2 == 0){
                    l  = ls;
                    ls = ls.next;
                }
                else{
                    ls = ls.next;
                }

            }
            return l;
        }
    }
```

When I run this code of a list of items: `[3,2,6,9]`, it returns `[2,6,9]` when it should only return `[2,6]`.  The duplicate method duplicates the ListItem, and the length method determines the length of the list.  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you duplicating the initial list? You would want to initialize an empty list and then add the even numbers to it and return that list.

Comment: I've tried initiating an empty list and the same issue is occuring

Comment: Are you dealing with a **LinkedList**?

Comment: No, I'm dealing with a list of items, similar to list nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try to keep your logic:

```
public static ListItem evenElements(ListItem ls) {
    ListItem output = null;

    ListItem current = ls;

    // While the next item exists
    while (current != null){

        // If it's even
        if (current.number % 2 == 0) {

            // If it's the first time we see an even number, initialize output
            if (output == null) {
                output = current.duplicate();
            }
            // Otherwise append this even number to our list of even numbers
            else {
                output.next = current.duplicate();
                output = output.next;
            }
        }
        // Move the next item
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (output != null) {
        output.next = null;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: this answer has been flagged as a low quality answer, please provide some explanation for you work.

Comment: @Henri Lapierre As this is a method to find even numbers, your comments should refer to even numbers, not odd...

Comment: As it's unclear if duplicate() duplicate only the element, or the element plus all it's successor, I added a line at the end "output.next = null;". This will ensure that even if the successor get copied, that we get rid of them before returning.